# Bash script as build command for Netlify

Tags: linux, bash, jekyll, netlify

I have a Bash script to build my Jekyll sites using different config files depending on environment variables, etc. Is it possible to specify a Bash script as build command in Netlify?
So far, my efforts have resulted in

```
3:57:24 PM: Executing user command: /opt/repo/build.sh
3:57:24 PM: /usr/local/bin/build: line 32: /opt/repo/build.sh: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is the current build command you are running?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The build commands in a Netlify deploy start at the root of your repository location, so you should be using a relative path `./build.sh` rather than an absolute path.

This would allow for a Netlify container location change in the future.

Comment: Thanks. My build command was `build.sh` when of course it should have been `./build.sh`.

Comment: Netlify allows for a lot of freedom here so you can build scripts for use in the site build. Most users are not aware of the ability to also use node scripts that allow native commands using modules like the `child_process`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the repo is not in `/opt/repo` but in `/opt/build/repo`